# Get Selected Value of SelectedItems in a TextBox (separated with Commas) from MultiSelect ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, listboxitems

Please tell me how can I get `ValueMember` of `ListBox` `SelectedItems`? I have read many tutorials but still I am unable to solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
int c = subjects_Listbox.Items.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (subjects_Listbox.GetSelected(i))
    {
        txt.Text += subjects_Listbox.SelectedIndices[i].ToString();
        txt.Text += ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of *reading many tutorials* ? Can you show your code?

Comment: Use edit button under the question and update your question with this code.

Comment: Do not post code in comments. Click the Edit link under your question and add the relevant code there using the appropriate formatting tool **{}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect. Just try this (this iterate through all `SelectedIndices` of your `ListBox` and will add them to your `TextBox`):

```
foreach (var item in subjects_Listbox.SelectedIndices)
{
     txt.Text += item;
     txt.Text += @", ";
}
```

Or even better:

```
txt.Text = string.Join(",", subjects_Listbox.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>());
```