# Get Selected ValueMember of Selected Items in a textbox (separated with Commas) from MultiSelect ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, listboxitems

Please tell me how can I get ValueMember of ListBox SelectedItems. Any help will be greatly appreciated.I am able to get the selectedindexes but I want selectedvalue of each selected displaymember of multiselected listbox in a textbox separated with commas.

```
subjects_Listbox.DataSource = dt; 
subjects_Listbox.DisplayMember = "subject_title";
subjects_Listbox.ValueMember = "subject_id";
```

My datasource is a `DataView` so my selectedItems are of type `DataRowView`.

Comment: You have already asked the same question two hours ago and accepted and answer there. What's happening now?

Comment: I have populated my list box with database table and bind that as datasource as:
`subjects_Listbox.DataSource = dt;
 subjects_Listbox.DisplayMember = "subject_title";
 subjects_Listbox.ValueMember = "subject_id";`

Now i just wants to get the multiple selected value member in a textbox separated with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code . Not optimized but works

```
    private string[] listItem = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h","i" };
    private List<string> selectedItem = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadItem();
    }

    private void LoadItem() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listItem.Count(); i++)
        {
            lstItem.Items.Add(listItem[i]);
        }
    }

    private void btnGetSelectedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int CountSelectedItem = lstItem.SelectedItems.Count; 
        for (int i = 0; i < CountSelectedItem; i++)
        {
            string text = lstItem.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
            selectedItem.Add(text);   
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItem.Count; i++)
        {
            txtSelectedItem.Text = txtSelectedItem.Text + "," + selectedItem[i]; 
        }
    }
```

I have populated few items in ListBox. and on Button Click generates the textbox with selected item from the listbox.

Comment: The problem is that the OP's datasource is a DataRowView, not a String. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238374/get-selected-value-of-selected-items-in-a-textbox-separated-with-commas-from-m#comment56220762_34238591)